# Choosing the right Minimum API for Android Studios

Tags: android, android-studio, android-api-levels

If I were to choose minimum API 4.1, does it mean the features in 4.0 will not be available to me if I use 4.1 as my minimum API? Or with each new API you get all the older features as well as the new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you get all the older features.  The minimum means that features newer than that will not be available on all devices, and that you need to check the version before attempting to use them (or risk a crash).

Comment: So if I use Android SDK 4.1 as my minimum SDK and version 5.0 has added a feature like screen capture and sharing, does it mean this particular feature won't work with SDK 4.1?

Comment: It won't work on any phones running 4.1.  It will run on a phone with 5.0 running your app, but you need to ensure NOT to use that feature on a 4.1 phone or it won't work (and will likely crash).  You may get a warning in your IDE that it won't work, you can get rid of that with an @TargetAPI annotation (but it won't stop it from crashing if called on a lower api phone).

Comment: So I can't create an app with any type of screen capture feature unless I use Android minimum SDK 5.0?

Comment: If the feature is required for your app, no. Or you need to find a work around. If it's a feature your app can work without, you can just not display the option to do it if the device is to low

Comment: Thank you for your help.